# Setup Angular2 App with threejs (or any canvas based lib)

Tags: angular, architecture, three.js

I am currently learning Angular2 and I am trying to create a more or less standard Angular2 CLI app but combined with threejs.

Three js should create a canvas in the background of the app and I want to keep the three related code as separate as possible from the rest of the code but want to communicate from Angular to three ans vise versa.

I created the Angilar2 CLI app with three like the following:

```
ng new
npm install -save three
typings install dt~three --global --save
```

The question is, what would be he best architecture to achieve this? I saw some examples that have totally different approaches. One is creating a render service in a shared/services folder and another one creating simply a three directory with a component / module and all the three related stuff.

Also should the 3D related assets go into the angular assets folder or better in a separate dedicated folder?

What would be the recommended way to setup such a project and best practice? I guess this relates also to similar libs that use canvas. E.g when Angular2 should be used as a UI for canvas visualizations or games. That is what I would like to understand. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm looking to achieve the same thing for a future ThreeJS project integrated inside a Angular2 website generated with Angular-cli. Goal is to have the ability ThreeJS interact with Angular2 and inverse way. Like Carsten said, there is multiple project with different approaches but none that implement exactly what is asked here. React interesting integrations exists also, like https://github.com/Izzimach/react-three and another link inside this repo (toxicFork repo) where every ThreeJS functions is rewrited for React.